# Get order Id from user Id wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to get order Id from user Id but I can't return from is_array function.
Please help me.
Thanks

```
public function get_order_id( $order_id = 0 ) {
        global $wpdb;
        if(is_array($order_id) ){
            $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ref_id 
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}user_items WHERE user_id = %d AND item_id = %d AND ref_type= %s",
                $order_id['user_id'],
                $order_id['course_id'], 'order');
            $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I want to get order id of user id. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code, maybe it will work for you -

```
function get_customerorderid(){
  global $order, $post;

  if( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
    $order_id = $post->ID;
  } else {
    $order_id = $order->id;
  }

  // Get the user ID
  $user_id = get_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', true);

  return $user_id;
}
```